# Want the difference between 2 columns to show as 0 and - based on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a template file with more than 300 rows and I am preparing the difference between 2024 and 2025 in columns B and C respectively. The difference is in column D.
Not every row has an amount, about 50 rows has amounts and I want to filter the difference column to populate only the rows that have amounts in either B or C. My challenge is when the amounts in column B and C are identical, the difference shows as 0 and when I filter these rows are not visible.

In the past, I have come across a report in which the rows that have identical amounts show a difference of 0 and rows where there are no amounts, the difference shows as "-". I am trying to replicate this without converting the data to a table. I tried using an If formula =IF(B=C,"0.00",B-C), this returned 0.00 as text and went to the bottom of the filter dropdown.

Sample data below:

| Category | Budget 2024 | Budget 2025 | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Services | 1000 | 1500 | 500 |
| Maint. | 1000 | 1000 | 0 |
| Misc. | 0 | 0 | 0 |

If i place a filter in difference column, and remove 0, then both Maint. and Misc. will be removed. I want to show Maint. because there are budget amounts in 2024 and 2025. Hope my query is clear.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
IF(AND(B2=0, C2=0), "-", B2-C2)
```

But what you calculate is difference not variance.

Comment: Yes, I guess i used the incorrect word. We have another column for variance %

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

[image]

---

```
=IFS(AND(B2=0,C2=0),"-",TRUE,B2-C2)
```

---

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this. :) Again this sends "-" to the bottom of the filter.

Comment: @Leonora doing the reverse may help, so what abt this `=IFS(AND(B2=0,C2=0),0,B2=C2,"-",TRUE, B2-C2)`

Comment: the - is going to the bottom of the filter